# How to append HTML5 video snapshots to a scrolling DIV without Jquery

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video

How can I take multiple snapshots (via onclick buttons) from an HTML5 video playing locally, and add the snapshot images with timestamp to a scrollable div without jQuery or external libraries?

I'm able to make a snapshot via canvas but how can I convert the canvas image to a small file size format and append the image (with a href="" scrpt) to a scrolling div?

codepine example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVGZEg

HTML

```
<span> Working example</span>
<br>


<video controls id="sourceVid">
    <source src="http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/media/elephants-dream-medium.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="../media/elephants-dream-medium.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
<canvas></canvas>
<br>
    <button id="snap" onclick="snap()">Take Snapshot</button>
<br>
<br>
    <br>
<!----------------------------------------
Desired Result
---------------------------------------->
<div id="DesiredResult" style="background-color:grey;width: 100%;">
<br>
Desired Result
<br>
    How can I take a snapshot & add it to scrolling DIV on the left?
    <br>
<video controls id="Result" style="float: left;" >
        <source src="http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/media/elephants-dream-medium.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="../media/elephants-dream-medium.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
<div id="snapshotscroll" >

<div id="snapshot#1" class="snapshots" style="background-color:#FE2E2E;" >
    snapshot image
    <br>#1
    </div>
    <div id="snapshot#1" class="snapshots" style="background-color:#FA5858;" >
    snapshot image
    <br>#2
    </div>
    <div id="snapshot#1" class="snapshots" style="background-color:#F78181;" >
    snapshot image
    <br>#3   
    </div>
    <div id="snapshot#1" class="snapshots" style="background-color:#F5A9A9;" >
    snapshot image
    <br>#4   
    </div>
    <div id="snapshot#1" class="snapshots" style="background-color:#F6CECE;" >
    snapshot image
    <br>#5   
    </div>
</div>
</div>
        <button id="snap" onclick="alert('How can I take a snapshot & add it to scrolling DIV on the left?')">Take Snapshot</button>


CSS

video, canvas {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#snapshotscroll {
overflow-y: scroll;
height:258px;
width:220px;
}
.snapshots {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

JAVASCRIPT



        // Get handles on the video and canvas elements
        var video = document.getElementById('sourceVid');
        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        // Get a handle on the 2d context of the canvas element
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // Define some vars required later
        var w, h, ratio;

        // Add a listener to wait for the 'loadedmetadata' state so the video's dimensions can be read
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
            // Calculate the ratio of the video's width to height
            ratio = video.videoWidth / video.videoHeight;
            // Define the required width as 100 pixels smaller than the actual video's width
            w = 200;
            // Calculate the height based on the video's width and the ratio
            h = 100;
            // Set the canvas width and height to the values just calculated
            canvas.width = w;
            canvas.height = h;          
        }, false);

        // Takes a snapshot of the video
        function snap() {
            // Define the size of the rectangle that will be filled (basically the entire element)
            context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            // Grab the image from the video
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
        }
```

Comment: I think this question should simply be rephrased to "How to take snapshots of HTML5 videos", and cut off the other part.

Comment: I think this question should be called "how to append an image to a DIV", since he has the snapshot part working already ha ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting your example working with a few tweaks. This example uses a counter to keep track of which div to append the snapshot to.

**Live Working Example (full screen it):**

```js
var w = 200, h = 100, snapnum = 1;

// Takes a snapshot of the video
function snap() {
    var cv = document.createElement("canvas");
    cv.width = w;
    cv.height = h;
    console.log(document.getElementById("snapshot#" + snapnum));
    document.getElementById("snapshot#" + snapnum).textContent = "";
    document.getElementById("snapshot#" + snapnum).appendChild(cv);
    var cx = cv.getContext('2d');
    cx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    // Grab the image from the video
    cx.drawImage(document.getElementById('Result'), 0, 0, w, h);
    snapnum++;
}
```

```css
video, canvas {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#snapshotscroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:258px;
    width:220px;
}
.snapshots {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!---------------------------------------- Desired Result ---------------------------------------->
<div id="DesiredResult" style="background-color:grey;width: 100%;">
    <br>Desired Result
    <br>
    <video controls id="Result" style="float: left;">
        <source src="http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/media/elephants-dream-medium.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="../media/elephants-dream-medium.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <div id="snapshotscroll">
        <div id="snapshot#1" class="snapshots" style="background-color:#FE2E2E;">snapshot image
            <br>#1</div>
        <div id="snapshot#2" class="snapshots" style="background-color:#FA5858;">snapshot image
            <br>#2</div>
        <div id="snapshot#3" class="snapshots" style="background-color:#F78181;">snapshot image
            <br>#3</div>
        <div id="snapshot#4" class="snapshots" style="background-color:#F5A9A9;">snapshot image
            <br>#4</div>
        <div id="snapshot#5" class="snapshots" style="background-color:#F6CECE;">snapshot image
            <br>#5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="snap" onclick="snap()">Take Snapshot</button>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/y80m3z33/

Comment: @PixelPimp Glad it worked for you! Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark to the left so it turns green. Thanks!

Comment: Thank Maximillian Laumeister you awesome! Im amazed to finally see it working. I deleted a few lines of code to get the result i was looking for [JSFiddle Version link](https://jsfiddle.net/PixelPimp/k94tg0fy/3/)  I still have a few things to figure out... how do i attach individual links to the to the snapshots? how do i get rid of the spaces between snapshots without changing font size to 0 in CSS because I eventually want to overlay timestamps and such text over them? Thanks for your help

Comment: @PixelPimp To attach individual links to each snapshot, I would wrap each snapshot div in an <a> tag with an href. And to get rid of the space between snapshots, give the canvases display: block. Hope that helps!